# Real-time profiling of Rails in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling

How can I do real-time profiling of Rails when it's in a development environment?

I've got a large task being run (it isn't done in the background on the development machine, but that wouldn't help anyway because I need to have the task run before I can interact with the web application further), and the task is taking so long I haven't yet seen it finish. So I assume something like ruby-prof probably won't work, because that relies upon there being a start, and a finish, and calculating how much time was taken up in the meantime by what methods.

Control-C profiling won't work either, because the Rails application doesn't respond to control-C, and doing `kill -9` kills it, but doesn't produce a stacktrace.

I'd like something that can display how much time was spent in what methods (or in garbage collection) in the past few seconds or the past few minutes, preferably without killing the Rails process in the process.

I could try reducing the size of the task being run, but that feels like a hack.

I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370195/rails-real-time-profiler , but that's for applications in production, and doesn't have any answers.

I'm not able to run the application in production mode on my local machine.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is an "rails application monitor". Google for that and see what you can find. There are a ton of apps out there to choose from.

Comment: Sounds like a tough one. Other platforms have tools like jstack or lsstack.